# Initialization by user-defined constructor

Tags: c++, initialization

Consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A(int, int){ std::cout << "A(int, int)" << std::endl; }
};

A a(4,4);
A b{4,4};
A c({4,4});

int main(){ }
```

Output:

```
A(int, int)
A(int, int)
A(int, int)
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07a4f106a40a3a7a)**

I' m intereste in is there a difference between initialization of `a`, `b` and `c`? Any of theme is direct initialized.

Comment: `c` constructs a temporary and then copies (but this can be elided). `a` and `b` ends up doing the same thing in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A a(4,4);
```

Bog standard *direct-initialization*.

```
A b{4,4};
```

Bog standard *direct-list-initialization*. Since `A` has no `initializer_list` constructor, this ends up doing the same thing as above. No `std::initializer_list` object is ever constructed or destroyed.

```
A c({4,4});
```

This *direct-initializes* `c` from an `A` temporary, which is in turn *copy-list-initialized* from the *braced-init-list* `{4, 4}`. Note that this won't work if `A::A(int, int)` is `explicit`, since in that case the copy-list-initialization would be ill-formed and you are left with no viable constructor to call. The construction and destruction of the temporary may be elided, and usually is.

Comment: Since `c` will be constructed from an `A` temporary, I believe `c` will be **copy-initialized** instead of being **copy-list-initialized**. If you define a copy constructor you'll see that it will be called after the temporary was constructed, with copy-elision disabled of course.

Comment: @Nard No, `c` is direct-initialized from the temporary. The temporary is copy-list-initialized from the braced-init-list.

Comment: @TC It seems I was unclear about the difference between **direct-initialization** and **copy-initialization**. The above results in a **direct-initialization** from the `A` temporary, whereas `A c = A();` would result in a **copy-initialization**. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: I dont' understand why is the temporary creating in the last case? 8.5/17 [dcl.init]: _Otherwise, if the source type is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type, conversion functions are considered._ The destination type is not a class type, therefore this rule is not applicable here as well as two previous cases represented in the clause.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv The applicable bullet is 8.5/17.6.1 (N4140). The candidate constructors are `A::A(const A&)`, `A::A(A&&)` and `A::A(int, int)`. The third one is nonviable because of argument number mismatch. The first two are viable because you can find a constructor to construct a temporary `A` from the *braced-init-list* for the reference to bind to (and then since it's a temporary, `A::A(A&&)` ends up being selected).